# TS Gateway Server - internal clients connect fine but external clients see error "server certificate has expired or has been revoked."

Tags: windows, windows-terminal-services

I have a GoDaddy SSL certificate installed on my Terminal Services Gateway server. I can successfully connect to terminal services computers through the TS Gateway when I'm on the LAN. However,if I try to connect from an outside network, I get the error "the remote desktop gateway server certificate has expired or has been revoked."

What might be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use HTTPS on the LAN?

Also, what does your topology look like, is your TS gateway simply nat'ed behind a firewall or is there some sort of forefront gateway in front of it for external clients?

I would start simply by looking at the cert on your IIS server and confirm that you have the correct one registered.  My intial guess is that you're using HTTP internal which would explain why your cert show expired only on the outside (assming you have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect here).